# Using AWK or SED how can I remove any line where the first column's character count doesn't equal 13

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Using AWK or sed how can I remove any line where the timestamp (first column) is not equal to 13 numeric characters while ignoring the first line.

Before:

```
timestamp,pageNo,description
1451317591621,01,Home Page Request
14513,Home Page Request
1451317591623,03,Home Page Request
1451317,04,Home Page Request
1451317591625,05,Home Page Request
```

After:

```
timestamp,pageNo,description
1451317591621,01,Home Page Request
1451317591623,03,Home Page Request
1451317591625,05,Home Page Request
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk` (requires gawk 4+ or 3+ with --re-interval option)

```
awk -F, '$1~/^[0-9]{13}$/||NR==1' file
```

Using `sed`

```
sed '/^[0-9]\{13\},/p;1p;d' file
```

Comment: The `sed` command is not doing what the OP asked. It looks like the `awk` command is not either.

Comment: @MadPhysicist it is for me..., whats it doing wrong ?

Comment: It's checking the entire line, not the first column.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`, pass if the line number is one or the first field consists of exactly thirteen digits; else, delete.

```
sed -r -e '1b' -e '/^[0-9]{13},/b' -e d file
```

Using Awk, similarly, print if line number is one or the first field is thirteen characters and all numbers.

```
awk -F , 'NR == 1 || (len($1) == 13 && $1 ~ /^[0-9]*$/)' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 || (length($1) == 13 && $1+0 == $1)' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If Perl is an option:

`perl -F, -ane 'print if $F[0] =~ /^[0-9]{13}$/ or $. == 1' file`

These command-line options are used:

- `-n` loop around each line of the input file
- `-a` autosplit mode – split input lines into the `@F` array.  Defaults to splitting on whitespace.
- `-e` execute the perl code
- `-F` autosplit modifier, in this case splits on `,`

`$.` is the line number
`@F` is the array of words in each line, indexed starting with `$F[0]`

output:

```
timestamp,pageNo,description
1451317591621,01,Home Page Request
1451317591623,03,Home Page Request
1451317591625,05,Home Page Request
```